# Max Payne 3 Steam crash

Tags: max-payne-3

I missed playing Max Payne 3 when it came out and bought it on Steam recently.

Unfortunately the game crashes every time at the same scene when I rescue Rodriguez from the van in the garage in the first chapter. As soon as Max opens the door and he comes out, the game crashes.

I already tried playing the scene without full-screen and with -safemode option.

I am running a 2600k, two 970s in SLI (tried with SLI disabled already) and Win10. Latest drivers and everything of cource.

Any ideas what to do? Did not found anything interesting on google yet concidering this specific issue.

Comment: I tried and couldn't reproduce that, My specs that didn't crash: i5, 8gb ram, win10, steam, GT820m. Can it be your AMD CPU causing that?

Comment: It is an Intel 2600K so no AMD CPU. What settings are you running?

Comment: Low ;(, however 2600k sounds old. That might cause it.

Comment: Well its a Sandy Bridge and way more new than Max Payne 3 :D Thanks however.. I just checked the integrity of files and it said 18 files are corrupted and I am now redownloading these. Maybe this will fix it, otherwise I will report back

Comment: Waiting on it :)

Comment: Yes that fixed it :)